# Error when inserting data into AS400 using C# Application

Tags: c#, .net, db2

I'm using .Net framework 4.0. and I've the the source code like this:

```
....
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
{
   cmd.Connection = conn;
   String query = "SELECT a.process_id, a.prod_dt, a.vlt_dt, a.prod_month, a.karoseri, a.error_flag, a.created_by, date_format(a.created_dt, '%Y%m%d') as created_dt, a.updated_by, date_format(a.updated_dt, '%Y%m%d') as updated_dt FROM tb_t_vlt_web a " +
                        "WHERE a.process_id = '" + processId + "'";
                    DataTable dt = CSTDDBUtil.ExecuteQuery(query);
   if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
   { 
      as400Con = CSTDDBUtil.GetAS400Connection();
      as400Con.Open();

      using (OdbcCommand as400Cmd = new OdbcCommand())
      {
          as400Cmd.Connection = as400Con;
          as400Cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DCDLIB.TBTVLT(VLPRID, VLPRDT, VLVLDT, VLPRMO, VLKRCD, VLERFG, VLCRBY, VLCRDT, VLCHBY, VLCHDT) VALUES " +
                            "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

          foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
          {
              as400Cmd.Parameters.Add("1", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = dr["process_id"].ToString();
              as400Cmd.Parameters.Add("2", OdbcType.Numeric).Value = dr["prod_dt"];
              as400Cmd.Parameters.Add("3", OdbcType.Numeric).Value = dr["vlt_dt"];
              as400Cmd.Parameters.Add("4", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = dr["prod_month"].ToString();
              as400Cmd.Parameters.Add("5", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = dr["karoseri"].ToString();
              as400Cmd.Parameters.Add("6", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = dr["error_flag"].ToString();
              as400Cmd.Parameters.Add("7", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = dr["created_by"].ToString();
              as400Cmd.Parameters.Add("8", OdbcType.Numeric).Value = dr["created_dt"];
              as400Cmd.Parameters.Add("9", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = dr["updated_by"].ToString();
              as400Cmd.Parameters.Add("10", OdbcType.Numeric).Value = dr["updated_dt"];

              as400Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              as400Cmd.Parameters.Clear();
         }
         as400Cmd.Dispose();
     }
}
... Next Process Below ...
```

When I execute the program, there is an error occurred on `as400Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`. The error was:

```
ERROR [00000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Column 4: CWB0111 - Input data is too big to fit into field
ERROR [22001] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Column 4: Character data right truncation.
```

And then, I've checked the AS400 and there is no problem with the column size.
How can I resolved this error..?
Structure table of TBTVLT
[image: Structure Table TBTVLT]

Comment: You've given the stack trace, but not the exception message... that's obscured the most crucial piece of information.

Comment: I've change my source code, and then I got another error message like above.

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell what the actual problem is easily because you haven't given us the error message, but the *first* thing to do is stop doing this:

```
insertQuery = String.Format("INSERT INTO DCDLIB.TBTVLT(VLPRID, VLPRDT, VLVLDT, VLPRMO, VLKRCD, VLERFG, VLCRBY, VLCRDT, VLCHBY, VLCHDT) VALUES " +
    "('{0}',{1},{2},'{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}',{7},'{8}',{9})",
```

*Never* build up SQL queries by inserting values into the SQL itself. Instead, you *parameterized SQL*, and add the parameters to the command.

This will:

- Keep your SQL easier to read
- Avoid SQL injection attacks
- Avoid unnecessary string conversions

I wouldn't be at all surprised if the problem is due to date/time to string conversions.

See the ["Using Parameters"](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Parameters.html) MySql documentation for examples.

Comment: Hi Jon, I've changed my source code, and then I got another error. Thanks for your response.